# Unable to click an element with Dynamic ID - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to access an element with dynamic ID. I have tried many options but I keep getting the same error:

```
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
```

The element is inside a frame, then I used the following to switch frames:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='classicContainer']")))
```

To locate the element I have tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=button]//button[@onclick= 'a459608b-9025-eb11-aa0d-0a687e2aa3e0']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=button]//button[starts-with(@id,'_')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=button]//button[contains(@id,'_')]"))).click()
```

[image]

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format or link to the page? Are you also able to switch to iframe successfully ? Do we have just one iframe ?

Comment: Also those xpath are off since none have that value. It isn't in onclick as well due to recipe_view_click is forgotten.

Comment: //button[@onclick="recipe_view_click('a459608b-9025-eb11-aa0d-0a687e2aa3e0')"] try the following.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan it seems to be dynamic id. How can you suggest to use that locator?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Thank you for pointing out that something was missing. I managed to click the button using //button[contains(@onclick, 'a459608b-9025-eb11-aa0d-0a687e2aa3e0')]